# Sort users by custom user meta value

Tags: users, post-meta, user-meta, order, wp-user-query

I'm trying to sort users by a custom meta value "user_business" which is their business name that way when users are listed they're sorted alphabetically by their business name as they should be.

I'm currently using:

```
<?php
                        // WP_User_Query arguments
                        $args = array (
                            'exclude'        => array( 1 ),
                            'count_total'    => true,
                            'fields'         => 'all_with_meta',
                        );


                        // The User Query
                        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

                        // The User Loop
                        if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
                            foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) { ?>
```

Is there a way that I can order users by meta key "user_business"?

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98580/sort-get-users-by-custom-field/98610

Comment: This solution will not work for me as it involves adding another custom field which isn't an option seeing as site users will come and go and I don't want to have to edit the meta value for each one every time they need reordered. I want something much more dynamic.

Comment: That is not a complete answer for your circumstance-- if I had the time I'd write one-- but using that filter is the approach you need to take.